# ubuntu/linux bash: traverse directory and subdirectories to work with files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

let me start off with what I need; the program is given a directory, it will then examine all the files in the directory (works) and do stuff to the files (waiting till it can find all the files for this part). then it will look for subdirectories and re-run its self for each subdirectory.

the directory I'm testing with looks like this:

```
desktop/test_files/ (starting directory)
desktop/test_files/folder 1/
desktop/test_files/folder 1>folder 2/
desktop/test_files/folder 1>folder 2/<files, 20 or so>
desktop/test_files/folder 3/
desktop/test_files/folder 3/<more files, 20 or so>
```

folders and files do contain spaces in the names

the output is:

```
$ ./x007_shorter.sh Desktop/test_files/

Desktop/test_files/"folder 1"/
Desktop/test_files/folder 1/"folder 2"/
ls: cannot access */: No such file or directory
Desktop/test_files/folder 1/folder 2/"folder 3"/
./x007_shorter.sh: line 4: cd: ./folder 3/: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access */: No such file or directory
```

here is the program:

```
#!/bin/bash
function findir {
    newDir=$1
    eval cd $newDir
    ARRAY=( $(ls -d */) )
    declare -a diry
    count=0
    a=0
    while [ $a -lt ${#ARRAY[@]} ]; do
        diry[$count]="${ARRAY[$a]}"
        noSpace=true
        while [ true ]; do
            if [[ ${diry[$count]} == */* ]] ; then
                if [ $noSpace = false ]; then
                diry[$count]="${diry[$count]:0:((${#diry[$count]}-1))}\"/"
                fi
                break
                noSpace=true
            fi
            let "a=$a+1"
            if [ $noSpace = false ]; then
                diry[$count]="${diry[$count]} ${ARRAY[$a]}"
            else
                diry[$count]="\"${diry[$count]} ${ARRAY[$a]}"
            fi
            noSpace=false
        done
        let "count=$count+1"
        let "a=$a+1"
    done
    for a in `seq 1 ${#diry[@]}`; do
        eval cd .$newDir
#        list "${diry[($a-1)]}"
        where=`pwd`
#        eval cd $newDir
        #findir "${diry[($a-1)]}"
        #findir "$where${diry[($a-1)]:1}"
        #Right option won,  echo "${diry[($a-1)]} Vs $where/${diry[($a-1)]}"
        echo "$where/${diry[($a-1)]}"
        findir "./${diry[($a-1)]}"
    done
}
function list {
    input_file_directory=$1
    eval cd $input_file_directory
    ARRAY=( $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print) )
    declare -a files
    count=0
    a=0
    while [ $a -lt ${#ARRAY[@]} ]; do
        files[$count]="${ARRAY[$a]}"
        while [ true ]; do
            if [[ ${ARRAY[(($a+1))]} == ./* ]] ; then
                break
            fi
            if [[ "${ARRAY[(($a+1))]}" == "" ]] ; then
                break
            fi
            let "a=$a+1"
            files[$count]="${files[$count]} ${ARRAY[$a]}"
        done
        let "count=$count+1"
        let "a=$a+1"
    done
    where=`pwd`
    for a in `seq 1 ${#files[@]}`; do
        echo "$where${files[($a-1)]:1}"
        #going to work on each file, just echoing file till lists all files
    done
}

clear
dar=""
if [[ $1 = "" ]]; then
    read -p "Please enter a directory for me to scan" newdir
    dar=$newdir
    list $newdir
    findir $newdir
else
    dar=$1
    list $1
    findir $1
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris J's answer is the preferred way to do things if you can put the per-file stuff in a separate command(/script).  If you want everything in a single script, my favorite incantation is something like this:

```
while IFS="" read -r -d $'\000' file <&3; do
    dostuffwith "$file"
done 3< <(find -x  "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

See [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) and [#89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) for explanations and some other options.  Note that this only works in bash (i.e. the script *must* start with #!/bin/bash).  Also, it processes the contents of a given directory in alphabetic order, rather than files-before-subdirectories.

If you really want to step through the files "by hand" (i.e. to get more control over the traversal order), here's how I'd do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

process_dir() {
    local -a subdirs=()
    echo "Scanning directory: $1"

    # Scan the directory, processing files and collecting subdirs
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
            echo "Processing file: $file"
            # actually deal with the file here...
        elif [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
            subdirs+=("$file")
            # If you don't care about processing all files before subfolders, just do:
            # process_dir "$file"
        fi
    done

    # Now go through the subdirs
    for d in "${subdirs[@]}"; do
        process_dir "$d"
    done
}

clear
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    read -p "Please enter a directory for me to scan " dir
else
    dir="$1"
fi
process_dir "$dir"
```

Answer (score 6):

Any reason you can't use find for this? Stick the per-file operation you want in it's own script (I've called it dostufftomyfile.sh below), then do:

```
find $dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dostufftomyfile.sh
```

Replacing $dir with the top level directory you'll be searching from...

**Edited to add...**
When you write the shell script, make sure you put $@ in double-quotes... e.g., you'll want your dostufftomyfile.sh script to have this structure:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in "$@"
do
    echo "Processing file: $f"
    # Do something to file $f
done
```

if you don't quote $@ then the spaces in filenames will be ignored (which I suspect you won't want) :-)

Comment: Why not `find "$dir" -type f -exec dostufftomyfile.sh {} +`?

Comment: It depends how efficient you want it to run and how many files you're dealing with. -exec will execute the script once for each file. Piping through xargs results in less executions of the script as xargs batches files up and passes multiple files through on the command line. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with using -exec, it's just that it can be slower :-)

Comment: The `-exec ... +` construct (as opposed to `-exec ... ;`) passes multiple files in much the same way that `xargs` does.  Unfortunately, not all implementations of `find` support this.  Note: you should quote `"$dir"` in the `find` command.

Comment: I've tried the find command multiple times and it kept listing the directories as well as files, but this does do what I needed nicely, however I still like to be able to control the files and directories like in mine.

Comment: @Gordon - Ahh -- I've not come across the '+' construct before; guess that's what comes of learning trad UNIX and then learing the GNU extensions as and when I need them :-)

Comment: @vzybilly ... you have to specify "-type f". If you don't specify this, then you'll get every file back. -type specifies the type of file you want 'find' to return, so it's 'f' for file, 'd' for directory, 'l' for sym-link, etc. If you're specifying "-type f" and it's still returning directories, then you'll need to provide more information (how you're calling find, etc). If you mean that the file has is given as the *full path name*, then in the  'dostufftomyfile.sh' script, you can get the base file by calling basename, e.g.: "filenameonly = `basename $f`" (note the use of backticks).

Answer (score 0):

You have the error `"No such file ....`  due to this

`ARRAY=( $(ls -d */) )`

When its expanded, directories with whitespaces will get stored in array as individual elements. eg `Desktop/test_files/folder 1/folder 2/"folder 3"/`.

In the array, element 0 will be `Desktop/test_files/folder`, element 1 will be `1/folder` and so on. That's why your script can't find the directory.

You can set the `IFS` to $'\n' before assigning to the array

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
ARRAY=($(ls -d */))
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```