# How to randomly change GDM background image on Linuxmint [Ubuntu]

Tags: bash, ubuntu, background, linux-mint

i was reading this thread [ubuntu/linux bash: traverse directory and subdirectories to work with files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954458/ubuntu-linux-bash-traverse-directory-and-subdirectories-to-work-with-files) and i thought maybe it can be twisted a little bit

Can this be set to:

1. be given a base folder
2. scan folder + subfolder
3. collect all files it finds (only images)
4. pick one randomly
5. write a symbolic link to /user/share/backgrounds directory (writing the image itself overwriting existing one may work as well)

what i intend is to execute the script upon system shutdown or at set interval so it will change the gdm background image..

this is based on a step to do it manually with this line
**sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/**

which prompts for the appearance dialog on startup, which writes the link.
Ideally, it would have a GUI to do it at will, and an option to "change it automagically upon restart" which will do the process i described above and add itself to system start, reboot or shutdown sequence.

Since theres no working utility atm for this, it might come handy for some people =)

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wallpapoz. It can change wallpapers randomly across workspaces and over time.

Comment: errr no, i didnt make myself clear, it is NOT desktop wallpaper, it is the GDM background image, the one on login/locked screen.

And desktopnova its way better tha wallpapoz ;)

Comment: The login screen background image is specified I think in the grub.cfg file. The grub.cfg file is not something you want to modify for each time you log in.